# Fill browser window with HTML5 video

Tags: jquery, css, html, video, fullscreen

I'm trying to make an HTML5 video fill the full width and height of the browser window.

Creating a full screen video background is relatively simple, but what I want to do is to have the video but with content below it. As the video will be full screen, the content will be immediately after the 'fold' when a visitor starts scrolling.

Help, advice or direction massively appreciated!

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.

Comment: A video in full screen mode and user scrolling, i don't understand it?!

Comment: `html, body { height: 100%; width: 100% }` will help you. Then just simply make the video have a 100% width and height.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you haven't provided any markup or samples, so I'm making some assumptions, but this should work for what you need:

Let's assume the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <video></video>
    <article>
        <p>This is content after the fold...</p>
        <p>This is content after the fold...</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, you can easily size the `video` element as follows:

```
$(function() {  
    var winHeight = $(window).height();
    $('video').css({  'height': winHeight, 'width': '100%'});
});
```

[<kbd>**jsFiddle Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/nzd3G/)

Comment: @robertc, thanks. I suspect that he wants it to be the full *viewport* width :)